# Where is my inheritance?

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, audio

Apparently, it's not a good week for relatives. My friend's grandfather [just recently passed away](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30889/help-me-with-our-discovery), and now my grandfather has died too! He was quite messy, and I had to help clean out his belongings. He managed to collect quite a lot during the years, but nearly everything was in poor condition. We found a large clock with only one hand, a huge safe with the door stuck, a filing cabinet partially broken and full of non-sensical papers, and even an old issue of Playboy! In short, he had all kinds of stuff...

While I was going through all his things, I suddenly remembered that he gave me a USB stick some weeks before his death, and told me, "This is your inheritance!" Due to lack of time I never looked at it, but while taking a break during the cleanup, I plugged it into my computer and opened it up. I was quite disappointed to find that it contained only two seemingly simple files.

There was text file with the line `Find me, and unlock me!` and an audio file with this song ([here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1sxdnm9jkznve26/my_precious.wav?dl=0)). I could not find anything useful from it... but maybe you can help me find my inheritance? What do I have to look for, and how can I unlock it?

**Update**: While browsing mindlessly on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oqBAst-t0J0) today, I found something which sounds really similar, but not totally. I could not find out, what, but something was odd...

**Update II**: I recognized something while listening to the version of my grandfather: It seems to go faster and slower at some times. Might be a hint?

Comment: Do you have your original, unadulterated file? The one I pulled off doesn't quite match (lead-in silence, and considerably longer for being the same song) ... unless that is the point, but it's hard to compare them when one is stretched out!

Comment: @feelinferrety: Well, that is the point you should start with (except the silence at the beginning). The length is what is odd in comparison... But why?

Comment: Modified my answer. Any luck?

Comment: No, sorry. Commented your post

Comment: The song speeds up at a certain time... Could it mean the clock is (supposed to be) that amount of time FAST? As in, turn the hand on the clock forward by the time at which the song speeds up (converting minutes to hours and seconds to minutes) and a compartment in the clock will open up?

Comment: The song speeds up at a certain time... Could it mean the clock is (supposed to be) that amount of time FAST? As in, turn the hand on the clock forward by the time at which the song speeds up (converting minutes to hours and seconds to minutes) and a compartment in the clock will open up?

Comment: @WeckarE.: Nice idea, you are close(r) to the solution! (Rather not "at", but "for")

Comment: It's been two years. There's something in the safe. Drill it already.

Answer (score 5):

In case anybody couldn't tell, the song is...

> *My Grandfather's Clock*. This most likely indicates that the inheritance will be found inside a clock, perhaps even the one taken note of during cleanup.

Okay, so having found the (apparent) source on YouTube, this potential heir should be aware that...

> Grandpa's version is approximately 2.136 seconds shorter than the original, so perhaps that's a good place to start? I'm not sure if setting the hand to 2 or slightly later may unlock the clock.

*// Old Notes*

> There **is** a solid line traversing the whole song, when plotted properly but I don't know much about audio analysis.

Probably not, but hey, it's worth a guess...

> The title of the audio file is "my-precious.wav", so I'm guessing that you've been left a ring and you will find it in the clock. Haha. Probably not. Oh well. Good luck to everyone else.

Comment: If you're talking about the tone at 11.8 kHz, it looks like some sort of compression artifact.

Comment: Part one detected, part II still remains hidden...

Comment: Should we move the hand on the clock to 11.8?

Comment: @ChrisCudmore: No, I managed to get more information...

Comment: It is rather about the speed and the time...